# Pushing multiple items into an array within an instance of a class

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, instance

I am trying to construct the addTopping method such that it can take in multiple toppings to push into the toppings array instead of one.  I'm not sure how to tackle this. I've seen some of the other posts using `.push.apply()` which doesn't work in my case since that creates an object.

```js
  class Pizza {

      constructor(size, crust, stuffedcrust) {
        this.size = size;
        this.crust = crust;
        this.stuffedcrust = stuffedcrust;
        this.toppings = ["Cheese"];
      }

      addTopping(topping) {
        this.toppings.push(topping);
      }

      removeTopping(topping) {
        let index = this.toppings.indexOf(topping);
        this.toppings.splice(index, 1);
      }

      }

      let pizza1 = new Pizza("Medium", "thin", true);

      pizza1.addTopping("Pepperoni", "Green Peppers", "Mushrooms");
      console.log(pizza1);
```

`pizza1.addTopping` will only add the first item as of now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to collect all `addToppings()` arguments in an array, and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the array to arguments for the `Array.push()` function:

```js
class Pizza {

  constructor(size, crust, stuffedcrust) {
    this.size = size;
    this.crust = crust;
    this.stuffedcrust = stuffedcrust;
    this.toppings = ["Cheese"];
  }

  addToppings(...toppings) { // rest
    this.toppings.push(...toppings); // spread
  }

  removeTopping(topping) {
    let index = this.toppings.indexOf(topping);
    this.toppings.splice(index, 1);
  }

}

let pizza1 = new Pizza("Medium", "thin", true);

pizza1.addToppings("Pepperoni", "Green Peppers", "Mushrooms");

console.log(pizza1);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had tried the spread operator before but was incorrectly using it considering I didn't include it within my method arguments as well!  This was very helpful, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps take a look over at [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). I think it'll get you what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use **function.arguments**, but it is deprecated.

source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments